# Looping a list returning a value in dict

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to read from a list and return a corresponding value in a dict.
Please help me where I am going wrong.
Thank you

```
DICT = {"b": "21", "g": "54", "f": "121", "t": "1", "j": "33"}
n = ['b', 'w', 'f']

for keys in n:
    if keys in n:
        if n == DICT.keys():
            print(DICT.values())
        else:
            if keys not in n:
                print('Not Available')
```

Comment: what errors are you getting when you run this?

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting the wrong output? Is there an error?

Comment: looks like your identation is all messed up, or is it just the SO formatting?

Comment: `for keys in n: if keys in n:` seems wrong. You're iterating over the keys that are in `n`, so checking to see if each individual key is in `n` is at best redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple if you use `get`

```
for k in n:
    print(DICT.get(k, 'Not Available'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in n:
    if key in dict.keys():
        print(dict[key])
```

Seems this is what you are trying to do

Comment: In your code you do an O(n) lookup in the list of all dictionary keys to see if the key is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier if you used the get() method:

```
DICT = {"b": "21", "g": "54", "f": "121", "t": "1", "j": "33"}
n = ['b', 'w', 'f']


for key in n:
    if DICT.get(key):
        print(DICT[key])
    else:
        print("Not available")
```

It produced the following output:

> 21
>  Not available
>  121

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over all elements of n, but checking to see if n is all the keys of the dictionary each loop, which it will not be. Try doing this:

```
for key in n:
    if key in DICT:
        print(DICT[key])
    else:
        print('not available')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>for keys in n:
       if keys in DICT.keys():
           print DICT[keys]
       else:
           print ('Not Available')

21
Not Available
121
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print '\n'.join((DICT[key] for key in n if key in DICT))
```